# best way to implement Apriori in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

What is the best way to implement the Apriori algorithm in pandas? So far I got stuck on transforming extracting out the patterns using for loops. Everything from the for loop onward does not work. Is there a vectorized way to do this in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

trans=pd.read_table('output.txt', header=None,index_col=0)

def apriori(trans, support=4):
    ts=pd.get_dummies(trans.unstack().dropna()).groupby(level=1).sum()
    #user input

    collen, rowlen  =ts.shape

    #max length of items
    tssum=ts.sum(axis=1)
    maxlen=tssum.loc[tssum.idxmax()]

    items=list(ts.columns)

    results=[]
    #loop through items
    for c in  range(1, maxlen):
        #generate patterns
        pattern=[]
        for n in  len(pattern):
            #calculate support
            pattern=['supp']=pattern.sum/rowlen
            #filter by support level
            Condit=pattern['supp']> support
            pattern=pattern[Condit]
            results.append(pattern)
   return results

results =apriori(trans)
print results
```

When I insert this with support 3

```
        a  b  c  d  e
0                    
11      1  1  1  0  0
666     1  0  0  1  1
10101   0  1  1  1  0
1010    1  1  1  1  0
414147  0  1  1  0  0
10101   1  1  0  1  0
1242    0  0  0  1  1
101     1  1  1  1  0
411     0  0  1  1  1
444     1  1  1  0  0
```

it should output something like

```
   Pattern   support
    a         6
    b         7
    c         7
    d         7
    e         3
    a,b       5
    a,c       4
    a,d       4
```

Comment: Your return is in the wrong place and for n in len(pattern) is wrong too....

Comment: @AndyHayden The first one was from pasting error when I was doing it by hand the pattern length does not work because I have not figured out how to generate the pattern combinations such as a,b; a,c; or a,b,c

Comment: How is support defined?  I had a guess, but it doesn't square with your a,d value (I thought it would be 4, but you say it's 3.)

Comment: @DSM if I were to use support =4 instead of 3 all the rows with support=3 would be discarded

Comment: No, I mean I don't know what "Support" means.  Why is "a,d" 3?

Comment: @DSM Support means proportion of transactions in the data set which contain the itemset.It is suppose to be 4 (mistake because I calculated visually), "a,d"=4 because a and d appear together 4 times at 666, 1010, 10101, 101   
here is an visual explanation of what I am trying to get
http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~zaiane/courses/cmput499/slides/Lect10/img054.jpg

Comment: That looks more like a count than a proportion.  If it's a proportion, what's the denominator?

Comment: @DSM it is suppose to be a fraction with denominator collen. But I left it out so on both support(a percentage) and its calculation(ie. sum column 'a'/collen) to make it easier to track the math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're after, maybe

```
from itertools import combinations
def get_support(df):
    pp = []
    for cnum in range(1, len(df.columns)+1):
        for cols in combinations(df, cnum):
            s = df[list(cols)].all(axis=1).sum()
            pp.append([",".join(cols), s])
    sdf = pd.DataFrame(pp, columns=["Pattern", "Support"])
    return sdf
```

would get you started:

```
>>> s = get_support(df)
>>> s[s.Support >= 3]
   Pattern  Support
0        a        6
1        b        7
2        c        7
3        d        7
4        e        3
5      a,b        5
6      a,c        4
7      a,d        4
9      b,c        6
10     b,d        4
12     c,d        4
14     d,e        3
15   a,b,c        4
16   a,b,d        3
21   b,c,d        3

[15 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Yep that is it. But is there a way to do it with just pandas?

Comment: @user3084006: I'm not sure, and unfortunately I'm out of time to spend on this question.  Hopefully someone else can help you!

Comment: Thanks you got the basic problem solved I should probably post another question

Comment: Just to be sure; there are more efficient ways to find frequent itemsets, see my comments here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112047/24783

Answer (score 0):

add support, confidence, and lift caculation。

```
def apriori(data, set_length=2):
    import pandas as pd
    df_supports = []
    dataset_size = len(data)
    for combination_number in range(1, set_length+1):
        for cols in combinations(data.columns, combination_number):
            supports = data[list(cols)].all(axis=1).sum() * 1.0 / dataset_size
            confidenceAB = data[list(cols)].all(axis=1).sum() * 1.0 / len(data[data[cols[0]]==1])
            confidenceBA = data[list(cols)].all(axis=1).sum() * 1.0 / len(data[data[cols[-1]]==1])
            liftAB = confidenceAB * dataset_size / len(data[data[cols[-1]]==1])
            liftBA = confidenceAB * dataset_size / len(data[data[cols[0]]==1])
            df_supports.append([",".join(cols), supports, confidenceAB, confidenceBA, liftAB, liftBA])
    df_supports = pd.DataFrame(df_supports, columns=['Pattern', 'Support', 'ConfidenceAB', 'ConfidenceBA', 'liftAB', 'liftBA'])
    df_supports.sort_values(by='Support', ascending=False)

    return df_supports
```